# Photosynthesis in Higher Plants

Tags: homework

Q:Photosynthesis in C4 plants is relatively less limited by atmospheric CO2 levels because: 1) Four carbon acids are the primary initial CO2 fixation products 2) the primary fixation of CO2 is mediated via PEP carboxylase 3) Effective pumping of CO2 into bundle sheath cells 4) RuBisCO in C4 plants has higher affinity for CO2.    Now the correct option is 2 but can you explain the reason for not choosing 4th option?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions, you are **required** to show your attempt to answer the question and to use the "homework" tag. ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case, why would C4 plants make PEPcarboxylase the primary acceptor instead of RuBisCO? Since it is not so, C4 plants were forced to take this alternative and make RuBisCO confined only to the bundle sheath cells. The problem in C3 was photorespiration, since oxygen used to competitively inhibit the uptake of carbon dioxide by RuBisCO. Hence it turns out that RuBisCO has more affinity for oxygen. If RuBisCO had more affinity for CO2, C4 plants would not have required to take the alternative pathway that they follow.

For the fact that why C4 remains unaffected by atmospheric CO2 levels is that because PEP carboxylase concentrates CO2 levels inside bundle sheath cells. So no matter what is the atmospheric CO2 level, the level inside bundle sheath cells remain always high and perfect for RuBisCO to act upon.